# Is it possible in SQL to count the number of distinct values as well?

Tags: sql

I am thinking that this statement will and should pick the distinct values from my table and then also have a count of them or at least that is what I would like in a separate column. Is it possible to count the number of distinct values in SQL, from what I am gathering probably not.

**Question: Can I count the number of distinct values of last names?**

SQL Statement:

```
select distinct c.LastName as 'Distinct Last Names', COUNT(*)
from Customer as c;
```

### Error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Customer.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

### Output -- Without the count

### 'Distinct Last Names'

LTest1
LTest2
LTest3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the result in two columns.

If so, you can use **[Group By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)**.

```
SELECT c.LastName as 'Distinct Last Names', COUNT(*) 
FROM Customer as c
GROUP BY c.LastName
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return an inflated number if last name wasn't unique to begin with?

Comment: @ckuhn203 **GROUP BY** and **DISTINCT** are basically same if you are not aggregating data. However, OP wants aggregating data, so **GROUP BY** is required.

Answer (score 3):

Since you donot have a `Group by` clause in the query, All your columns in the `Select` should use some kind of an aggregation or else `SQL` will not be happy.

Try this

```
select COUNT(distinct c.LastName) 'Distinct Last Names'
from Customer as c;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a subquery for this. The inner query returns a distict list of last names. The outer query counts the distict values. I prefer count(1) over count(*) because there's no need to return metadata for all of the columns in the customer table.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT LASTNAME 
    FROM CUSTOMER
) a
```